# WebApi DateTime formatting

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

My understanding is that WebApi V2+ uses JSON.Net formatter that uses IsoDateFormatter by default. But it does not seem to be working as expected. Here is example of HTTP GET that I tried.

http://www.mydomain.com/api/ServerTime?RequestTime="2014-07-17T15:20:09.747Z"

RequestTime parameter is populated by getting UTC time on client. When request gets to server side, RequestTime gets deserialized into DateTime.Min value i.e. 01/01/0001 .....
This is not what I was expecting.
I am aware of adding custom DateTime formatter in configuration to probably get around this. That would be my last option if WebApi is supposed to support ISO dates.

Thanks

Comment: Remove the double quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON.NET is used for binding the body and that's where media formatters come into play. For a query string like yours, binding is same as MVC model binding and JSON.NET is not used.

Comment: Perfect. I changed the signature to form the request data object using [FromBody]. Now everything is happy.